# Gnome-Arch no Terminal

Tags: arch-linux, terminal, software-installation, gnome, system-installation

Another one of the million noobs lost with my first installment of Linux. I have Gnome up through Arch but I can’t get the terminal to open. I’ve searched for days with no luck. I don’t have the English option for my input in the settings either. Alt F-1 to F-9 doesn’t work either and I’ve tried downloading other terminals but can’t seem to install them without a preexisting terminal. 
Any and all help would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance for any replies!

Comment: Have you tried the [shortcuts](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_shortcuts#Virtual_console) with `Ctrl` and `Fn`, e.g. `Ctrl+Alt+F1` or `Ctrl+Fn+Alt+F1`?

Comment: OK, those questions are all quite answerable but for the sake of clarity, please split them up -- StackExchange works best if a post contains only a single answer.

Comment: Thank you for your replies! Yes, I’ve tried all the Ctrl+Alt+F1-9 key options. And I only have one question; How do I get a working terminal in Arch-Gnome

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `gnome-terminal`?

You can either:

- Click "Activities" in the upper-left, type "terminal", and select the Terminal application from the results that appear.

or

- Hit the keyboard shortcut Ctrl - Alt + T (default shortcut)

Maybe you want to set your own keyboard shortcut.

- Open the Activities overview and start typing Settings.
- Click on Settings.
- Click Devices in the sidebar.
- Click Keyboard in the sidebar to open the panel.
- Click the row for the desired action. ...
- Hold down the desired key combination, or press Backspace to reset, or press Esc to cancel.

I have chosen Super + T